# SQL Server Management Studio autocomplete behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, red-gate-sql-prompt

I have SQL Server Management Studio 2008 with SQL Prompt 5. When I type in a query, and hit enter, the cursor jumps backwards to the middle of the word.

If I type

```
SELECT * FROM
```

and then select the table name from intellisense, this does NOT happen. But, if I type

```
SELECT * FROM account
```

and hit enter, the cursor jumps to in between the `c` and `o` in `account`.

I assume this is some sort of autocomplete setting, but I cannot figure out which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to turn the auto-complete off and on again. Try to hit the tab key instead of enter.

Comment: Resetting autocomplete seemed to do it.